# find and copy the file with different name in same folder

Tags: linux

I have same file name in all directory. now I just want to made backup copy of file in each directory.

for e.g:

```
/u/ABC/source/ $ find . -iname Makefile_ORG

./main/simulator/Makefile_ORG
./log/Makefile_ORG
./sds/Makefile_ORG
./lck_mgr/tool/Makefile_ORG
./lck_mgr/lock/Makefile_ORG
./lck_mgr/server/Makefile_ORG
./lck_mgr/interface/Makefile_ORG
./lck_mgr/interface/utest/Makefile_ORG
```

Now I just want top made copy of each `Makefile_ORG` to `Makefile`.

I tried this command:

```
$ find . -name 'Makefile_ORG' -exec cp "{}" Makefile \;
```

but get this error:

> cp: cannot create regular file 'Makefile': Permission denied

Comment: So, what are the permissions on those folders?

Comment: @underscore_d actually these files (Makefile_ORG ) are soft link. But when I am doing manually in each folder using comand cp Makefile_ORG Makefile. It is working fine.

Comment: You will also need to run execdir and not exec to ensure that the backup files are same directory as the originals.